# How to solve $\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{1+t}\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Is there a solution using $\Psi(x,t)$ such that

$$\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{1+t}\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$

?

I have tried $\Psi=te^xe^t$, $\Psi=te^xe^{t^2}$ and other similar variations, but could not get the powers of $x$ and $t$ to agree on both sides of the equation.

Is there a general method to solve this type of differential equation in 2 variables?

Comment: @gpmath I think it’s worth mentioning that $X(x)$ looks a bit different for $k<0$.

Comment: Your equation can be written in the form $$\psi_{t} = a(t) \psi + \psi_{xx}$$ If you let $\psi = e^{\int a(t) dt} \hat{\psi}$ you get $$\hat{\psi}_{t} = \hat{\psi}_{xx}$$ Now you can solve the problem in $\hat{\psi}$ and hence determine $\psi$. The solution will be depend on the boundary conditions which you haven't supplied.

Comment: Use separation of variables: $\Psi(x,t)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$.
Then you will find:

$$X(x)=c_1 e^{k x}+c_2 e^{-k x}$$
$$T(t)=(t+1) e^{k^2 t}$$

Comment: @gpmath thank you very much! i added the algebra verification below. It's hard to believe the superior power of math over naive human pattern searching :o

Comment: @gpmath the equation i am interested in is actually $\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{1+t^2}\Psi = \frac{d\Psi}{dt}$. I have tried to modify your solution for $\frac{1}{1+t}\Psi$ but cannot get a clean answer, could you perhaps show the working steps (or just the finished solution) to this equation, please?

Comment: $$\psi (x,t)=\left(c_1 e^{k x}+c_2 e^{-k x}\right) e^{k^2 t+\tan ^{-1}(t)}$$

Comment: @thank you once again

Comment: Better separation for $\frac{\partial ^2\psi (x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{1+t^2}\psi (x,t)=\frac{\partial \psi (x,t)}{\partial t}$ is:

$$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_k {(c_1 \cos (k x)+c_2 \sin (k x))\cdot e^{-k^2 t+\tan ^{-1}(t)} }$$

Comment: Fourier transform is the more general way to do it.  Avoiding the hypothesis of separating variable.

Comment: @EDX thank you. I seem to recall Fourier representation being that with infinite number of terms... in which cases will the number of Fourier terms be finite and small?

Comment: @James Hi James. You have the Fourier series (decomposition of a function into) which are indeed infinite sum of terms (in general case). You have also Fourier transform for a function which an integral defined and explained here, especially with its role in PDE https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equations_(Herman)/09%3A_Transform_Techniques_in_Physics/9.11%3A_Transforms_and_Partial_Differential_Equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show how to solve the PDE

$$\frac{\partial ^2\psi (x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{1+t^2}\cdot \psi (x,t)=\frac{\partial \psi (x,t)}{\partial t}$$

with the following separation of variables

$$\Psi(x,t)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$$

We are able to separate for variables $(x,t)$:

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}}_{k^2}+\underbrace{\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}}_{-k^2}=0$$

Then we solve both ODEs:

$$X(x)=c_1 \cos (k x)+c_2 \sin (k x)$$

$$T(t)=e^{-k^2 t+\tan ^{-1}(t)}$$

The general solution then is:

$$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_k {(c_1 \cos (k x)+c_2 \sin (k x))\cdot e^{-k^2 t+\tan ^{-1}(t)} }$$

**Example** with rectangular domain $x \in [0,1]$, $t \in [0,\infty)$

We choose initial condition $\Psi(x,0)=1$ and boundary conditions $\Psi(0,t)=\Psi(1,t)=0$.

We then get the example solution with the determination of the Fourier coefficients:

$$\Psi(x,t)=\frac{4}{\pi} \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 k-1} \sin (\pi  (2 k-1) x)\cdot \exp \left(-(\pi  (2 k-1))^2 t+\tan ^{-1}(t)\right)$$

Visualization:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it is with the Fourier transform.  If you take the Fourier transform in $x$, you are left with
$$(\frac{1}{1+t}-k^2)\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$
which is a separable 1st order differential equation in $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Verifying the solution kindly provided by @gpmath in the above commment:

Let $\Psi = X(x)T(t)$ where

$$X = c_1 e^{kx} + c_2e^{-kx}$$

$$T = (1+t)e^{k^2t}$$

Then

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} = T \frac{d^2X}{dx^2} = T \frac{d}{dx} (kc_1e^{kx} + kc_2e^{-kx})= T(k^2c_1e^{kx} + k^2c_2e^{-kx})=k^2 T X$$

and

$$ LHS = \frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} 
+ \frac{\Psi}{1+t} = k^2TX + \frac{X(1+t)e^{k^2t}}{(1+t)}=\boxed{X(k^2T+e^{k^2t})}$$

while

$$ RHS = \frac{d\Psi}{dt} = X\frac{dT}{dt}=X \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{k^2t} + te^{k^2t}\right)=X\left(k^2e^{k^2t} + k^2te^{k^2t} + e^{k^2t} \right)= \boxed{X(k^2T + e^{k^2t})}$$

$\therefore LHS = RHS$

---

More generally,

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + G(t) \Psi = \frac{d\Psi}{dt}$$

has a solution of the form

$$\Psi = XT$$

where

$$X = c_1e^{kx}+c_2e^{-kx}$$

and

$$T = e^{F(t)}$$

such that

$$\boxed{F'(t) = k^2 + G(t)}$$

since

$$LHS = \frac{d^2XT}{dx^2} + GXT = X(k^2 + G)T$$

$$RHS = \frac{dXT}{dt} = XF'T$$