# How to solve $\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

Is there a solution using $\Psi(x,t)$ such that

$$\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$

?

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694098/how-to-solve-frac-partial2-psi-partial-x2-frac11t-psi-frac-p) which solves $\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{1+t^2}\Psi = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$ using separation of variables method $\Psi = X(x)T(t)$.

Unfortunately, the separation of variables method does not seem to work for solving this modified form of $\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi$?

Comment: While this is tagged as quantum-mechanics, the PDE used isn't Schrodinger's equation: for that, it should be $$-\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi =i \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$ The minus signs and imaginary $i$ make a big difference for such equations, so this isn't an minor detail.

Comment: @Semiclassical thank you very much, i will correct. Please feel free to point out other mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose that $\Psi$ is of the form:

$$\Psi = a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2$$

where $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$ have the property that

$$\boxed{ \frac{d^2\Psi_1}{dx^2} = E_1\Psi_1\\ \frac{d^2\Psi_2}{dx^2} = E_2\Psi_2}$$

$$\boxed{ \Psi_1 = \Psi_3e^{-iE_1t}\\ \Psi_2 = \Psi_4e^{-iE_2t}}$$

$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \Psi_3 \Psi_4 dx = 0\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_3 \Psi_3 dx = 1\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_4 \Psi_4 dx = 1}$$

Then

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + \frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi = i\frac{d\Psi}{dt}$$

$$a\frac{d^2\Psi_1}{dx^2} + b\frac{d^2\Psi_2}{dx^2}+ a\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_1 + b\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_2 = i\Psi_3\frac{d}{dt}(a(t)e^{-iE_1t}) + i\Psi_4\frac{d}{dt}(b(t)e^{-iE_2t})$$

$$\color{red}{aE_1\Psi_1} + \color{red}{b E_2 \Psi_2} + a\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_1 + b\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_2 = i\Psi_1(\frac{da}{dt} - \color{red}{iE_1a}) + i\Psi_2(\frac{db}{dt} - \color{red}{iE_2a})$$

$$a\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_1 + b\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_2 = i\Psi_1\frac{da}{dt} + i\Psi_2\frac{db}{dt}$$

Multiplying all sides by $\Psi_3$ and integrating over $x$ to infinity:

$$ e^{-iE_1t}\int \Psi_3 a\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_3 +  e^{-iE_2t} \int\Psi_3 b\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_4 = i \frac{da}{dt} e^{-iE_1t} \color{orange}{(\int \Psi_3\Psi_3)} + i\frac{db}{dt}e^{-iE_2t} \color{orange}{(\int \Psi_3\Psi_4)}$$

Hence

$$ e^{-iE_1t}\int \Psi_3 a\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_3 +  e^{-iE_2t} \int\Psi_3 b\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\Psi_4 = i \frac{da}{dt} e^{-iE_1t} $$

so

$$ \frac{a(t)}{1+t^2}\int x^2 \Psi_3 \Psi_3 +  e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\frac{b(t)}{1+t^2} \int x^2 \Psi_3 \Psi_4 = i \frac{da}{dt} $$

Similarly,

$$ e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\frac{a(t)}{1+t^2} \int x^2 \Psi_4 \Psi_3 +   \frac{b(t)}{1+t^2}  \int x^2\Psi_4 \Psi_4 = i \frac{db}{dt} $$

Assuming further that

$$ \boxed{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \Psi_3 \Psi_3 dx = 0 \\\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \Psi_4 \Psi_4 dx = 0\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \Psi_3 \Psi_4 dx = A\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \Psi_4 \Psi_3 dx = B}$$

$$\boxed{a_{\{t=0\}} = 1\\b_{\{t=0\}} = 0}$$

we obtain

$$ \frac{da}{dt} = -iA b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right) $$

$$ \frac{db}{dt} = -iB a(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)  $$

This coupled first order differential equations behave in quite stable oscillations over time, eg. $|b(t)|^2$:

[image]

Replacing the one-off disturbance to periodic $V(t)=\cos(kt)$ (analytically derived [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgV9fEERiD0)), $|b(t)|^2$:

[image]

Reversing initial condition such that $a_{\{t=0\}}=0, b_{\{t=0\}} = 1, |b(t)|^2$:

[image]

Therefore given a time varying contraint, the probability of a transition from $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_2$ necessarily oscillates higher and lower over time (even for $t<0$) called [Rabi cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle). Measurement at specified times create true random binary number of specified probability.

---

Eg.

Suppose for the harmonic oscillator

$$\Psi_0 = \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{iE_0t}$$
$$\Psi_2 = \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x^2-1)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{iE_2t}$$
$$H = \frac{x^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$E_0 = \frac{1}{2}\hbar \omega$$
$$E_2 = \frac{5}{2}\hbar \omega$$

Then

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{t=-\infty}^\infty \bar \Psi_0 H \Psi_2 dtdx$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i(-E_0+E_2)t}}{1+t^2} \left(\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (2x^4 e^{-x^2} - x^2e^{-x^2})dx \right)dt$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i(-E_0+E_2) t}}{1+t^2} \left[\frac{3}{2}\sqrt\pi - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt\pi\right] dt$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\hbar \omega t}}{1+t^2}dt$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\pi e^{-2\hbar \omega}$$

since

$$\boxed {\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt \pi}$$

$$\boxed {\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4e^{-x^2} = \frac{3}{4}\sqrt \pi}$$

$$\boxed {\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikt}}{1+t^2} = \pi e^{-|k|}}$$

by Gaussian integration [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BQEoXdjONE), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJuGYrmn8XQ), and by  contour integration [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpT0maiGZAY).

---

Extending to the 1+1D Dirac constraint equation:

$$ \boxed{i\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&-1&0&0 \\ -1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \frac{d\Psi}{dx}  \color{red}{-A_0\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\Psi} = m\Psi}$$

Suppose that $\Psi$ is of the form:

$$\Psi = a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2$$

where $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$ have the property that

$$\boxed{ i\gamma_x\frac{d\Psi_1}{dx} = m_1\Psi_1 - i\gamma_t\frac{d\Psi_1}{dt}\\ i\gamma_x\frac{d\Psi_2}{dx} = m_2\Psi_2 - i\gamma_t\frac{d\Psi_2}{dt}}$$

$$\boxed{ \Psi_1 = \Psi_3e^{-iE_1t}\\ \Psi_2 = \Psi_4e^{-iE_2t}}$$

$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_4 dx = 0\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \bar \Psi_4 \gamma_t \Psi_3 dx = 0\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_3 dx = 1\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar \Psi_4 \gamma_t \Psi_4 dx = 1}$$

$$\boxed{ A_0 = A(t)A_x }$$

Then

$$i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i\gamma_x \frac{d\Psi}{dx} \color{red}{- A_0\gamma_t\Psi} = m\Psi$$

$$i\gamma_t \frac{d}{dt}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) + i\gamma_x \frac{d}{dx}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) - A_0\gamma_t(a(t)\Psi_1 - b(t)\Psi_2)= m_1a(t)\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\Psi_2$$

$$i\gamma_t \left(\Psi_3\frac{d}{dt}(a(t)e^{-iE_1t}) + \Psi_4\frac{d}{dt}(b(t)e^{-iE_2t}) \right) + i\gamma_x \left(a(t)\frac{d}{dx}(\Psi_1) + b(t)\frac{d}{dx}(\Psi_2)\right) - A_0a(t)\gamma_t\Psi_1 - A_0b(t)\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\Psi_2$$
and so
$$i\gamma_t \left(\frac{da}{dt}\Psi_1 - iE_1a(t)\Psi_1 + \frac{db}{dt}\Psi_2 -iE_2b\Psi_2 \right) + i\gamma_x \left( a(t)m_1\Psi_1 - ia(t)\gamma_t\frac{d\Psi_1}{dt} + b(t)m_2\Psi_2 - ib(t)\gamma_t\frac{d\Psi_2}{dt}\right) - A_0a(t)\gamma_t\Psi_1 - A_0b(t)\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\Psi_1+ m_2b(t)\Psi_2$$

Multiplying by $\bar \Psi_3$ and integrating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx$:

$$ i\frac{da}{dt}e^{-iE_1t}\color{orange}{\int\bar \Psi_3\gamma_t \Psi_3} + E_1a(t)e^{-iE_1t}\color{orange}{\int\bar \Psi_3\gamma_t \Psi_3} + i\frac{db}{dt}e^{-iE_2t}\color{orange}{\int\bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_4} +E_2b(t)e^{-iE_2t}\color{orange}{\int\bar \Psi_3\gamma_t \Psi_4} + im_1a(t)\int \bar  \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_1 - iE_1a(t)\int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_1 + im_2b(t)\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_2 - iE_2b(t)\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_2 - A(t)a(t) e^{-iE_1t}\int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_3 - A(t)b(t)e^{-iE_2t}\int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_4  = m_1a(t) \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_2$$
and so
$$ i\frac{da}{dt} + E_1a(t) + im_1a(t)\int \bar  \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_3 - iE_1a(t)\int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_3 + im_2b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_4 - iE_2b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_4 - A(t)a(t) \int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_3 - A(t)b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_4 = m_1a(t) \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_3+ m_2b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_4$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{ \frac{da}{dt} = a(t)\left( E_1\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_3} - m_1\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_3}  +iE_1- im_1 \color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_3} 
\color{red}{- i A(t)} \color{blue}{\int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_3} \right) + b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\left( E_2\color{blue}{\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_4} - m_2\color{blue}{\int  \bar \Psi_3\gamma_x\Psi_4} -i m_2\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_4}  \color{red}{- iA(t)}\color{blue}{\int A_x\bar \Psi_3  \gamma_t\Psi_4} \right) }$$

or

$$ \boxed {\frac{da}{dt} = k_1(t)a(t) + k_2(t) e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}b(t)}$$

and similarly,

$$\boxed{ \frac{db}{dt} = a(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\left(E_1\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_3} - m_1\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_x\Psi_3}  - im_1 \color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_4\Psi_3} \color{red}{- i A(t)} \color{blue}{\int A_x\bar \Psi_4  \gamma_t\Psi_3} \right) + b(t) \left( E_2\color{blue}{\int  \bar \Psi_4\gamma_x\gamma_t\Psi_4} - m_2\color{blue}{\int  \bar \Psi_4\gamma_x\Psi_4} +iE_2 - i m_2\color{blue}{\int \bar \Psi_4\Psi_4} \color{red}{- iA(t)}\color{blue}{\int A_x\bar \Psi_4  \gamma_t\Psi_4} \right) }$$

or

$$ \boxed {\frac{db}{dt} = k_3(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}a(t) + k_4(t) b(t)}$$

Assuming that most of the integrals evaluate to $0$, and $A(t)A(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)(x^2)$, the equations may reduce to

$$ \frac{da}{dt} = -iC e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}b(t)\left( \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)$$

$$ \frac{db}{dt} = -iD e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}a(t)\left( \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)$$

which gives an oscillating $a(t), b(t)$ solution as in the Schrodinger constraint equation.

---

Extending to the 3 dimensional spherical coordinates:

$$ \boxed{i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi}{dr} + i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} + i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi}  \color{red}{-A_0\gamma_t\Psi} = m\Psi}$$

Suppose that $\Psi$ is of the form:

$$\Psi = a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2$$

where $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$ have the property that

$$\boxed{ \Psi_1 = \Psi_3e^{-iE_1t}\\ \Psi_2 = \Psi_4e^{-iE_2t}}$$

$$\boxed{\int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \bar  \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_4 dx = 0\\\int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \bar \Psi_4 \gamma_t \Psi_3 dx = 0\\\int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_3 dx = 1\\\int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \bar \Psi_4 \gamma_t \Psi_4 dx = 1}$$

$$\boxed{ A_0 = A(t)A_r }$$

Then

$$i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi}{dr} + i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} + i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} \color{red}{- A_0\gamma_t\Psi} = m\Psi$$

$$i\gamma_t \frac{d}{dt}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) + i\gamma_r \frac{d}{dr}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) + i\gamma_\theta \frac{d}{d\theta}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) + i\gamma_\phi \frac{d}{d\phi}(a(t)\Psi_1 + b(t)\Psi_2) \color{red}{- A_0\gamma_t\Psi} = (m_1a(t)\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\Psi_2)$$

$$i\gamma_t \left(\Psi_3\frac{d}{dt}(a(t)e^{-iE_1t}) + \Psi_4\frac{d}{dt}(b(t)e^{-iE_2t}) \right) + i\gamma_r \left(a(t)\frac{d}{dr}(\Psi_1) + b(t)\frac{d}{dr}(\Psi_2)\right) + i\gamma_\theta \left(a(t)\frac{d}{d\theta}(\Psi_1) + b(t)\frac{d}{d\theta}(\Psi_2)\right)+ i\gamma_\phi \left(a(t)\frac{d}{d\phi}(\Psi_1) + b(t)\frac{d}{d\phi}(\Psi_2)\right) - A_0a(t)\gamma_t\Psi_1 - A_0b(t)\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\Psi_2$$

$$i\gamma_t \left(\frac{da}{dt}\Psi_1 - iE_1a(t)\Psi_1 + \frac{db}{dt}\Psi_2 -iE_2b\Psi_2 \right)+ ia(t) \gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_1}{dr} + ib(t) \gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_2}{dr} +  a(t)i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_1}{d\theta} + b(t)i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_2}{d\theta}+  a(t)i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_1}{d\phi} + b(t)i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_2}{d\phi} - A_0a(t)\gamma_t\Psi_1 - A_0b(t)\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\Psi_2$$

Multiplying by $\bar \Psi_3$ and integrating $\int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} dr d\theta d\phi$:

$$ i\frac{da}{dt}\color{orange}{\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_1} 
+ E_1a(t)\color{orange}{\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_1} + i\frac{db}{dt} \color{orange}{\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t\Psi_2} +E_2b(t)\color{orange}{\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3 \gamma_t \Psi_2} + ia(t) \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_1}{dr} + ib(t)  \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r\frac{d\Psi_2}{dr} +  a(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_1}{d\theta} + b(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_2}{d\theta}+  a(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_1}{d\phi} + b(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_2}{d\phi} - A(t)a(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_1 - A(t)b(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_1 + m_2b(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_2$$

and so

$$ i\frac{da}{dt} + E_1a(t) + ia(t) \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_3}{dr} + ib(t) e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t} \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r\frac{d\Psi_4}{dr} +  a(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\theta} + ib(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\theta}+  a(t)i\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\phi} + ib(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\phi} - a(t)A(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_1 - b(t)A(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_2 = m_1a(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_3 + m_2b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_4$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{\frac{da}{dt} = -im_1a(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_3 -i m_2b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\Psi_4 +i E_1a(t) - a(t) \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_3}{dr} - b(t) e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t} \int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_r\frac{d\Psi_4}{dr} - a(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\theta} - b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\theta} -  a(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\phi} - b(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_3\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\phi} -i a(t)A(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_3 -i b(t)A(t)e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_3\gamma_t\Psi_4 }$$

Similarly,

$$\boxed{\frac{db}{dt} = -im_1a(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\Psi_3 -i m_2b(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\Psi_4 + i E_2b(t) - a(t) e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi_3}{dr} - b(t)  \int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_r\frac{d\Psi_4}{dr} - a(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\theta} - b(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\theta} -  a(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_3}{d\phi} - b(t)\int \int \int \bar \Psi_4\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi_4}{d\phi} -i a(t)A(t)e^{i(E_2-E_1)t}\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_4\gamma_t\Psi_3 -i b(t)A(t)\int \int \int A_r \bar \Psi_4\gamma_t\Psi_4 }$$

---

Eg.

Using approximate hydrogen ground state solutions

$$ \Psi_1 = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-r} e^{-iE_1t}\\ 0 \\ i \cos\theta e^{-r}e^{-iE_1t}\\ i \sin\theta e^{i\phi}e^{-r}e^{-iE_1t} \end{bmatrix}, \Psi_2 =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ e^{-r}e^{-iE_2t} \\  i \sin\theta e^{i\phi}e^{-r} e^{-iE_2t} \\ - i \cos\theta e^{-r} e^{-iE_2t}\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$ \gamma_t = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} $$ $$ \gamma_r = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta e^{-i\phi} \\ 0 & 0 & sin \theta e^{i\phi} & -\cos \theta \\ -\cos \theta & -\sin \theta e^{-i\phi} & 0 & 0 \\ -\sin \theta e^{i\phi} & \cos \theta & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$ $$ \gamma_\theta = \frac{1}{r}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -\sin \theta & \cos \theta e^{-i\phi} \\ 0 & 0 & \cos\theta e^{i\phi} & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta e^{-i\phi} & 0 & 0 \\ -\cos\theta e^{i\phi} & -\sin\theta & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$ $$ \gamma_\phi = \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -ie^{-i\phi} \\ 0 & 0 & ie^{i\phi} & 0 \\ 0 & ie^{-i\phi} & 0 & 0 \\ -ie^{i\phi} & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

we obtain (triple integral $r$ from $0$ to $30$, $A_r = \frac{1}{r}$, unverified):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Therefore,

$$\boxed{ 25\frac{da}{dt} = -9im_1a(t) + 25iE_1a(t) - 120ia(t) + 3a(t) - 95ia(t)A(t) 
\\
25\frac{db}{dt} = -9im_2b(t) + 25iE_2b(t) - 42ib(t) - 95ib(t)A(t)}$$

which are uncoupled and thus non-oscillating.

---

Extending to magnetic vector potential:

$$ L_{QED} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + i\bar \Psi \gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i\bar \Psi \gamma_r\frac{d\Psi}{dr} + i \bar \Psi \gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} + i\bar \Psi \gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} - m\bar \Psi \Psi - q\bar\Psi \gamma_t A_t \Psi -q\bar\Psi \gamma_r A_r \Psi - q\bar\Psi \gamma_\theta A_\theta \Psi - q\bar\Psi \gamma_\phi A_\phi \Psi$$

Taking Euler-Lagrange procedure with respect to $\bar \Psi$:

$$ \boxed{i \gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} + i \gamma_r\frac{d\Psi}{dr} + i  \gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} + i \gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi}  - q \gamma_t A_t \Psi - q \gamma_r A_r \Psi - q \gamma_\theta A_\theta \Psi - q \gamma_\phi A_\phi \Psi = m \Psi}$$

Suppose $\Psi$ changes into

$$ \Psi \rightarrow e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi$$

and $A_t, A_r, A_\theta, A_\phi$ changes into

$$ A_t \rightarrow A_t - \frac{da(t)}{dt}$$
$$ A_r \rightarrow A_r - \frac{db(r)}{dr}$$
$$ A_\theta \rightarrow A_\theta - \frac{dc(\theta)}{dr}$$
$$ A_\phi \rightarrow A_\phi - \frac{dd(\phi)}{dr}$$

Then

$$i \gamma_t \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) + i \gamma_r\frac{d}{dr}\left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) + i  \gamma_\theta \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) + i \gamma_\phi \frac{d}{d\phi}\left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right)  - q \gamma_t (A_t- \frac{da(t)}{dt})\left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) - q \gamma_r (A_r- \frac{db(r)}{dr}) \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) - q \gamma_\theta (A_\theta- \frac{dc(\theta)}{d\theta}) \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) - q \gamma_\phi (A_\phi- \frac{dd(\phi)}{d\phi}) \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi\right) = m e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi $$

and

$$i e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\gamma_t \left(e^{iqa(t)}\frac{d\Psi}{dt} + iq\frac{da}{dt}e^{iqa(t)}\Psi \right) + i e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\gamma_r\left(e^{iqb(r)}\frac{d\Psi}{dr} + iq\frac{db}{dr}e^{iqb(r)}\Psi \right) + i e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqd(\phi)} \gamma_\theta \left(e^{iqc(\theta)}\frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} + iq\frac{dc}{d\theta}e^{iqc(\theta)}\Psi \right) + i e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}\gamma_\phi \left(e^{-iqd(\phi)}\frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} + iq\frac{dd}{d\phi}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi \right)  - \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\right)q \gamma_t (A_t - \frac{da}{dt})\Psi - \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\right)q \gamma_r (A_r - \frac{db}{dr}) \Psi  - \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\right)q \gamma_\theta (A_\theta - \frac{dc}{d\theta})\Psi  - \left(e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\right)q \gamma_\phi (A_\phi - \frac{dd}{d\theta}) \Psi = m e^{iqa(t)}e^{iqb(r)}e^{iqc(\theta)}e^{iqd(\phi)}\Psi$$
and
$$=e^\kappa i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} \color{orange}{- e^\kappa\gamma_tq\frac{da}{dt}\Psi}  + e^\kappa i\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi}{dr} \color{orange}{- e^\kappa\gamma_rq\frac{db}{dr}\Psi} + e^\kappa i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} \color{orange}{- e^\kappa\gamma_\theta q\frac{dc}{d\theta}\Psi} + e^\kappa i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} \color{orange}{- e^\kappa\gamma_\phi q\frac{dd}{d\phi}\Psi} - e^\kappa q \gamma_t A_t\Psi \color{orange}{+ e^\kappa q \gamma_t \frac{da}{dt}\Psi} - e^\kappa q \gamma_r A_r\Psi \color{orange}{+ e^\kappa q \gamma_r \frac{db}{dr}\Psi} - e^\kappa q \gamma_\theta A_\theta\Psi \color{orange}{+ e^\kappa q \gamma_\theta \frac{dc}{d\theta}\Psi} - e^\kappa q \gamma_\phi A_\phi\Psi \color{orange}{+ e^\kappa q \gamma_\phi \frac{dd}{d\phi}\Psi}= m e^\kappa \Psi$$
so
$$e^\kappa \left( i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} +  i\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi}{dr} +  i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} +  i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} -  q \gamma_t A_t\Psi -  q \gamma_r A_r\Psi -  q \gamma_\theta A_\theta\Psi -  q \gamma_\phi A_\phi\Psi\right)= e^\kappa (m\Psi)$$

$$\boxed{i\gamma_t \frac{d\Psi}{dt} +  i\gamma_r \frac{d\Psi}{dr} +  i\gamma_\theta \frac{d\Psi}{d\theta} +  i\gamma_\phi \frac{d\Psi}{d\phi} -  q \gamma_t A_t\Psi -  q \gamma_r A_r\Psi -  q \gamma_\theta A_\theta\Psi -  q \gamma_\phi A_\phi\Psi= m \Psi}$$

The cancellation of $e^\kappa$ leaves the above equation unchanged when $\Psi$ changes to $e^\kappa \Psi$.

Comment: Wow, this could be a published paper, lots of work. Unfortunately I did not read it carefully, no time for that, sorry. Any idea why it has been downvoted? As usual, this wretched practice of downvoting without explaining makes it impossible to understand what's wrong.